# Is there a way to access the Cosmos DB Gremlin API from Java / Kotlin similar to Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We want to use Cosmos DB Gremlin API from Java, respectively Kotlin, and wonder which is the best way to do so. We know the Tinkerpop gremlin-driver works. But is there a way that supports typed mapping in the way Spring Data does?

A first attempt would be https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin, but that's deprecated now. They recommend looking at generic spring data approaches (azure-sdk-for-java/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-cosmos and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spring-v3). With these generic approaches, it is not clear how to use graph-specific features like dealing with edges.

Here are the questions. Are there examples out there of how to deal with graphs with these generic approaches? Are they supposed to support the Gremlin language? Are there other libraries to access Cosmos DB Gremlin API from Java, respectively Kotlin?